# Draw hourglass recursively in C

Tags: c, function, recursion, definition

I need to draw an hourglass recursively in C. I need to have 1 helper function plus the actual function. Here are the function signatures:
void helper(unsigned int height, unsigned int offset)
void real(unsigned int height)

Where height describes the number of rows to draw, and offset is the number of spaces at the beginning of each row. For each row, the number of stars should decrease by 2, the offset should increase by 1, and the height should decrease by 1 until you reach the middle of the hourglass. After that, the height should continue decreasing, but the number of stars should increase by 2 and the offset should decrease by 1. If the input height is even, then the first row should have height - 1 stars. Additionally, the middle should have two rows of only 1 star. If the input height is odd, then the first row should have height stars.

```
Ex) height = 6
*****
 ***
  *
  *
 ***
***** 

Ex) height = 5
*****
 ***
  *
 ***
*****
```

I must use recursion, no loops allowed.

Here is what I have for the helper function. I'm having trouble figuring out the main function.

```
void draw_hourglass_rec_helper(unsigned int height, unsigned int offset)
 {

  if (height == 0) {
    printf("\n");
  } else if (offset == 0) {
    printf("*");
    draw_hourglass_rec_helper(height-1, 0);
  } else {
    printf(" ");
    draw_hourglass_rec_helper(height, offset-1);
  }
 }
```

Best attempt:

```
void draw_hourglass_rec(unsigned int height)
{
  if(height < 1)
  {
  return;
  }
 {
   draw_hourglass_rec_helper(height, ((-0.5 * height) + (9.0/2.0)));
   draw_hourglass_rec(height-2);
 }

}
```

prints :

```
**********
********
 ******
  ****
   **
```

for draw_hourglass_rec(10)
Couple problems 
 1) I can't print the bottom half of the hourglass 
 2) The number of stars should always be odd
 3) I don't know how to express the even input case where there should be 2 rows of 1 star each
 4) If I use this code on an odd height, I fall into an infinite loop.

This is my first week coding in C. I'm really having trouble expressing my logic in this language.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No need to post _all_ of your broken attempts, but your _best_ attempt would be helpful. _"I'm having trouble figuring out the main function"_: what problems are you having? Did you write the helper function yourself, or was it given to you?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I added my problems above. I wrote the helper function, but the function signature was given to me and I must use it.

Comment: you need to do something before AND after the recursive call First you print on your way down and then you print the same on your way up.

Comment: But won't that ruin the recursive call? Because if I call it on itself, it will do all of those things. Sorry if that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void draw_hourglass_rec_helper( unsigned int n, int offset )
{
    const char c = '*';

    if ( n )
    {
        printf( "%*c", offset + 1, c );

        unsigned int k = n % 2 == 0 ? n - 1 : n;

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++ ) putchar( c );
        putchar( '\n' );

        if ( ! ( n < 2 ) ) draw_hourglass_rec_helper( n - 2, offset + 1 );

        if ( n != 1 )
        {
            printf( "%*c", offset + 1, c );
            for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++ ) putchar( c );
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
    }
}

void draw_hourglass_rec( unsigned int n )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        draw_hourglass_rec_helper( n, 0 );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );

        unsigned int n;

        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );

        draw_hourglass_rec( n );

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 10

*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 9

*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 8

*******
 *****
  ***
   *
   *
  ***
 *****
*******

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 7

*******
 *****
  ***
   *
  ***
 *****
*******

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 6

*****
 ***
  *
  *
 ***
*****

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 5

*****
 ***
  *
 ***
*****

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4

***
 *
 *
***

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 3

***
 *
***

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 2

*
*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1

*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

If the second parameter of the helper function shall be of the type unsigned int then you can use a loop to output initial spaces as for example

```
void draw_hourglass_rec_helper( unsigned int n, unsigned int offset )
{
    const char c = '*';

    if ( n )
    {
        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < offset; i++ ) putchar( ' ' );

        unsigned int k = n % 2 == 0 ? n - 1 : n;

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < k; i++ ) putchar( c );
        putchar( '\n' );

        if ( ! ( n < 2 ) ) draw_hourglass_rec_helper( n - 2, offset + 1 );

        if ( n != 1 )
        {
            for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < offset; i++ ) putchar( ' ' );
            for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < k; i++ ) putchar( c );
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach is to use a static variable for the output offset instead of using a helper function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void draw_hourglass_rec( unsigned int n )
{
    static int offset = 0;

    const char c = '*';

    if ( n )
    {
        ++offset;
        printf( "%*c", offset, c );

        unsigned int k = n % 2 == 0 ? n - 1 : n;

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++ ) putchar( c );
        putchar( '\n' );

        if ( ! ( n < 2 ) ) draw_hourglass_rec( n - 2 );

        if ( n != 1 )
        {
            printf( "%*c", offset, c );
            for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++ ) putchar( c );
            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        --offset;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );

        unsigned int n;

        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );

        draw_hourglass_rec( n );

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output will be the same as of the program above.

Comment: I like it! The only design choice difference I made was making the `base == height` which results in a minimum width of 2 for even numbers. Who would have thought there would be so many different ways to approach a recursive hourglass `:)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the selections provided by [@Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow) there is yet another approach you can take that uses the same helper function for recursion, but that sets the initial height negative and the recursion ends when the height is greater than the original value entered, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void hghelper (int h, int current)
{
    if (current > h)
        return;

    int ac = abs(current);

    if (ac == 1)
        current = 1;

    if (ac != 0) {
        int stars = ac;
        int indent = (h - stars) / 2;

        while (indent--)
            putchar (' ');
        while (stars--)
            putchar ('*');
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    hghelper (h, current + 2);
}

void hourglass (int h)
{
    int negh = -h;

    hghelper (h, negh);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int height;

    if (argc > 1) {
        if (sscanf (argv[1], "%d", &height) != 1 || height < 0)
            return 1;
    }
    else
        height = 5;

    hourglass (height);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Note, for this algorithm, the base (width) always has the same number of stars as the height. You can adjust as desired.

Default `height = 5`:

```
$ ./bin/hourglass_recursive
*****
 ***
  *
 ***
*****
```

`height = 6`:

```
$ ./bin/hourglass_recursive 6
******
 ****
  **
  **
 ****
******
```

`height = 7`:

```
$ ./bin/hourglass_recursive 7
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

`height = 21`:

```
$ ./bin/hourglass_recursive 21
*********************
 *******************
  *****************
   ***************
    *************
     ***********
      *********
       *******
        *****
         ***
          *
         ***
        *****
       *******
      *********
     ***********
    *************
   ***************
  *****************
 *******************
*********************
```